# How to move axes to center of chart in Maxima draw

Tags: plot, center, draw, axis, maxima

The draw (2d) function in Maxima has several settings to control the axis, but as far as I can tell, none that sets the xy-axis to the center of the chart.

I did find the equivalent in the plot2d function, where I can just set [box, false].

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12749661/how-to-move-axes-to-center-of-chart) related question, that does it in gnuplot. Maybe that's possible to use with the option user_preamble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right. You'll use something like the following, with symmetric ranges for x and y.

```
load(draw)$
draw2d( user_preamble="set zeroaxis linetype 5; set xtics axis;
       set ytics axis; set border 0;", explicit(sin(x),x,-%pi, %pi))$
```

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks Fred! One more question. Do you happen to know whether it is possible to hide the zero labels on the axis and place an O for origin as the origin label?

Comment: You're welcome. I think I do know how to do those things, but ask that as a separate question--- the answer is too long for a comment.

Comment: thanks, I posted it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28088938/how-to-set-the-origin-to-o-and-remove-the-zero-labels-in-maxima-draw