# How to set the origin to O and remove the zero labels in Maxima draw?

Tags: gnuplot, draw, label, axis-labels, maxima

The draw (2d) function in Maxima has several settings to control the axis, but as far as I can tell, none that hides the zero label of the xy-axis and to replace it with either a 0 or a O.

Maybe that's possible to use with the option user_preamble?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the `xtics` and `ytics` values explicitly, omitting the origin, and use `label` to label the origin.

```
load(draw)$
draw2d( user_preamble="set zeroaxis linetype 5; set xtics axis;
   set ytics axis; set border 0;", 
   xtics={-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3},
   ytics={-1, -1/2, 1/2, 1},
   label(["O", 0, 0]),
   explicit(sin(x),x,-%pi, %pi))$
```

[image]

You can tweak the label coordinates if you don't want the origin label to appear right at the intersection in my example above. Replacing `label(["O",0,0])` with `label(["O", -0.15, 0.1])` gives

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works. I wish it was easier though.. Setting the ticks manually really is a hassle

Comment: There are other ways to do the xtics and ytics--- you can set a start, end, and increment that misses the origin if you're careful, or you can just set them with a single increment that misses the origin.  Either way the tics will be automatically generated.